# Coding an extension to control Chrome for automate trading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to code a chrome extension to control chrome browser for stock trading, such as, submit form, scraping data from a website. I want to make the extension able to to login in to a website and scraping data too.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you could try using content scripts - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: Do you have any idea how control content script with python or C+? I used before Selenium, but I am not how safe it is?

Comment: Controlling a content script with Python or C++ seems like a big security vulnerability since it would be risky for browser extensions to have access to the filesystem. You can control it with Javascript though. You could do something like: 
`usernameInput.value = "username"`
`passwordInput.value = "password"`
`loginButton.click()`

Comment: Thanks for your time and help! Is there condition I can set up with Javascript for example, if the price goes down, buy .. so on?

Comment: For that, you would actually have to view the source of the page and find a way to get the stock price by scraping the site.

Comment: Thanks so much! It was a big help!

Comment: Assuming the stock price is given as an array (Like so: [200.34, 190.56, 205.43]): `
var isBuy = true;
for (var i = 0; i < stockPrices.length; i++) { 
  if (i != 0) {
    if (stockPrices[i] > stockPrices[i - 1]) {
      isBuy = false
    } else {
      isBuy = true
    }
  }
}

if (isBuy) {
  // Buy stock
}`

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8850s/cz2tbg19/

Comment: Wonderful, is there recommendation to learn Javascript in particular area rather than learn everything about Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry my question was about how to learn coding in this particular area which is the stock trading. I am beginner in Javascript. Any recommendations is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For stock trading, you would need to learn basic Javascript, logic (boolean operators, etc), and web scraping (getting HTML from a web page and interacting with it using the Javascript DOM: Document-Object-Model)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much!

Comment: Could you guide me to the following: how can i make a temporary array for the last 100 stock pice value using Javascript?

Comment: I added the code to get an array of closing stock prices. Just change the `MSFT` stock symbol in the URL in the `getJSON()` function to get the stock of a different symbol. I would recommend that you change the second code sample because the one I gave only compares `i` and `i - 1`.

Comment: Awesome! If there is a number in html tag which change periodically. Is there a way to extract this number from the website and store it in array. The array will store only the  most recent numbers which will get updated periodically too. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Use `parseFloat(document.getElementById("<element-id>"))`. It seems you also have to store the array, so you'd need some kind of back-end database thing. I would recommend using NodeJS FS with JSON files. Use socket.io to send the file's content back and forth from the client to the server. Kind of seems like this would violate the CORS policy and wouldn't be possible, though. You could do it if you can iFrame the website with no problem, and use contentDocument/contentWindow on the iFrame to get the element.

Comment: Sweet, I will try this method. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the code. It's `parseFloat(document.getElementById("<element-id>").innerHTML)`

Comment: Sweet, thanks man!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use content scripts with Javascript. To login, you could do something like:

```js
usernameInput.value = "username"
passwordInput.value = "password"
loginButton.click()
```

For the logic to check if the stock is a buy, you would have to use something like the following code (assuming you get the stock prices as an array):

```js
var stockPrices = [200.4, 201.4]

var isBuy = true;
for (var i = 0; i < stockPrices.length; i++) {
  if (i != 0) {
    if (stockPrices[i] > stockPrices[i - 1]) {
      isBuy = false
    } else {
      isBuy = true
    }
  }
}

console.log(isBuy)
```

Here is some code that will get the closing price of Microsoft (change the stock symbol in the URL of the `getJSON()` function):

```js
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status, xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};

Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

var stockPrices = []

getJSON('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo',
  function(err, data) {
    if (err != null) {
      console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
    } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < Object.size(data["Time Series (Daily)"]); i++) {
                var x = data["Time Series (Daily)"][Object.keys(data["Time Series (Daily)"])[i]]
                stockPrices.push(x["4. close"])
            }
    }
    
    console.log(stockPrices)
  })
```